# AWS ElasticSearch Java Process Limit

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

AWS documentation makes clear the following:
[Java Process Limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html)

> Amazon ES limits Java processes to a heap size of 32 GB. Advanced users can specify the percentage of the heap used for field data. For more information, see Configuring Advanced Options and JVM OutOfMemoryError.

Elastic search instance types span right  up to 500GB memory - so my question (as a Java / JVM amateur) is how many Java processes does ElasticSearch run? I assume a 500GB ElasticSearch instance (r4.16xlarge.elasticsearch) is somehow going to make use of more than 32GB + any host system overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch uses one java process (per node).

Indeed as quoted it is advised not to go over the 32GB RAM from performance efficiency reasons (the JVM would need to use 64bits pointers, which would decrease performance).

Another recommendation is to keep memory for the file system cache, which lucene uses heavily in order to load doc-values, and info from disk into memory.

Depending on your workload, it is better to run multiple VMs on a single 500gb server. you better use 64gb-128gb VMs, each divided between 31gb for Elasticsearch and the rest for the file system cache.

- multiple VMs on a server means that each VM is Elasticsearch node.